# Splitting a Scala Seq dataset into a training and testing set

Tags: scala

In Scala, I have a dataset represented as Seq[T].
I would like to separate it out into a training dataset and a test dataset.
It is ok for this to be based in simple random sampling.
I know how to do this using a pair of ListBuffers etc. But is this formulation also correct?

```
def splitIntoTrainingAndTest[T](all: Seq[T], samplingRate: Double): (Seq[T], Seq[T]) = {
  val r1 = new Random(123)
  val r2 = new Random(123)
  (
    all.filter({ i: T => r1.nextDouble() < samplingRate }),
    all.filter({ i: T => r2.nextDouble() >= samplingRate })
  )
}
```

Note that I am using the same random seed for both `java.util.Random` instances. I am simply wondering whether the `.filter(…)` may, in the future, be implemented lazily...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably better off using the `partition` method of [Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.10.3/#scala.collection.Seq):

```
// Partitions this sequence in two sequences according to a predicate.
def partition(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): (Seq[A], Seq[A])
```

Then you can just do `all.partition(_ => r.nextDouble() < samplingRate)` with only a single RNG.

Answer (score 1):

For lazy evaluation you can convert this to `all` to a `Stream` and then use `partition` to split `all` into streams based on the predicate given. In your case this would be something like:

```
all.toStream.partition(_ < samplingRate)
```

which returns a `Tuple` of `Stream`s.

```
(scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int], scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int])
```